# PHP mysql database connect

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I am trying to store data using html form into mysql database.

It is somehow not working when I click submit it should work but it seems so, But the data is not stored in my database.

Here is my php code;

```
<?php
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "test_database";

@mysql_connect ("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die ("Could not connect to mysql!");
@mysql_select_db ("$db_name") or die ("No Database");

$value = $_POST['input1'];
$value2 = $_POST['input2'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO 'users' ('username','pid') VALUES ('$value')('$value2')";

echo "Hello World!";


mysql_close();
?>
```

and here is my other php file which includes the form

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>

<body>

<form action = "mysql_connect.php" method="post" />
<p>Input 1: <input type="text" name="input1" /> </p>
<p>Input 1: <input type="number" name="input2" /> </p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your SQL yet not executed ...

Answer (score 1):

You have not executed the SQL.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 'users' ('username','pid') VALUES ('$value')('$value2')";

mysql_query($sql) or die ("Failed Executing");

echo "Hello World!";
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use following in place of existing SQL Query your executing

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'users' ('username','pid') VALUES ('$value', '$value2')") or die (mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the SQL-line with:

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'users' ('username','pid') VALUES ('$value', '$value2')");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 'users' ('username','pid') VALUES ('$value'), ('$value2')";
```

This will prepare insert query string.

But you need to call `mysql` api to insert data.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be:

```
<?php
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "test_database";

$conn=mysql_connect($db_host,$db_username,$db_pass) or die ("Could not connect to mysql!");
mysql_select_db ($db_name,$conn) or die ("No Database");

$value = $_POST['input1'];
$value2 = $_POST['input2'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username,pid) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($value)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($value2)."')";
$q=mysql_query($sql);
if($q){
echo "Inserted!";
}
else
{
  echo "Not inserted";
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

Buddy, before ask something , please research deeply.

Answer (score 0):

You are no executing your sql statement. Execute your sql statement, this will work for you.

```
if(mysql_query($sql)){ echo "Data inserted successfully."; }else{ echo "Unable to execute query." };
```